# Add column from another table using excel power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am having below 2 table in excel

**table-1**

```
Organization    Server name Contract    OS Type Server Category Server Type Server Status   DB Instance Status  Environment CPU Cores   Instance Full Name  DB Instance name    DB Software name    Version Edition DB Instance size (GB)   DB datasize (GB)    CG Support
XXXXX XXXXXX    SV021   021             Linux   Virtual_System  Virtual Machine In Production   In Production   Production  1   8   DB-ODIPRD   ODIPRD  Oracle Database Server  Oracle-12.1.0.2.0   Standard    733.21  670.43  Yes
```

and
**table-2**

```
Full name   Status->name    Product category->name  Software item->Smtc product catalog id type Managed by provider Collected date  Description.1   Description.2
ODIPRD      In Production   DB  Oracle Database Server  Yes 21-02-2023  Oracle-12.1.0.2.0   Standard
```

Based on the **Instance Full Name** and **Full Name** need to get the **Status->name** from table-2

**Expected**

```
Instance Full Name              Full Name         Status->name
DB-ODIPRD                       ODIPRD            In Production
```

I tried by adding `Custom Column` and `#"table-1"[#"Status->name"]{0}` in table-2 but the data is not coming as expected please let me know on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge the first table and second table with left outer join, then use arrows atop the the new column to expand [x] Status>name field

[image]

Comment: Come now, you got like 12 of them yesterday, leaving me to answer those where the people will never come back for the answers. But I did like my array one, even if 2 hours late

Comment: True but then I have a long way to go until I catch you up so I need to focus my efforts... :D.

Comment: @horseyride: Thanks for your response. I forgot to mention on thing. both the table are having different number of columns. so merge will not work. only the `name` column mention in the example is common in both the tables

Comment: The number of columns in each table is irrelevant. Follow the image and directions  I provided above.  There are many resources for step-by-step instructions on merging if needed